# vector::empty() function doesn't work correctly in release mode

Tags: multithreading, vector, is-empty

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<thread>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

vector<string> s;

void add()
{
    while(true)
    {
        getchar();
        s.push_back("added");
    }
}

void show()
{   
    while(true)
    {
        //cout<<"";
        while(!s.empty())
        {
            cout<<(*s.begin())<<endl;
            s.erase(s.begin());
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread one(add);
    thread two(show);

    one.join();
    two.join();
}
```

In debug mode there is no such a problem. In release mode if the comment line is uncommented it works again. But with just like this, there is a problem. What is the problem?

Comment: Your code is broken, since you have two threads manipulating the vector without synchronization. Use a mutex.

Comment: But it works with {cout<<"";}

Comment: It may seem to work, but that isn't reliable. Seriously, get a tutorial on multithreading, it will explain things.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` (as any other `std::` container) is not generally thread-safe. It means that concurrent modifying access to the same vector from multiple thread is generally not supported. What that means is that while you can call non-modifying functions of the vector from many threads at the same time (for instance, you can call `begin()` and `end()` with no problems), modification functions should have exclusive access to the vector object. To achieve this exclusivity, you need to use thread-synchronization primitives to 'signal' your intention to obtain exclusive access to the vector, perform your modification and than 'signal' that exclusive access is no longer need.

Note, this is not enough to perform that sort of routine when you modify (insert) data to the vector. You will also have to do the same dance when you read data from the vector, since modifications need exclusive access, and even the read will violate this exclusivity. The non-technical term I've used here, 'signalling', has a technical counterpart - it is called critical section. Here we say that you 'enter critical  section' and 'leave critical section'.

There a more than one way to enter and leave critical section. The stapples of this are so-called `mutexes`, and they should be enough for your learning. Just keep in mind there are other ways as well, which you'll learn in the due course.